# Circle Pong detect ball and arc shaped paddle collision

Tags: java, java-2d, pong

I'm trying to create a game exactly like circle pong. I have created a paddle that moves along the circumference of the circle. Note that the paddle is arc'd shaped. I'm wondering how would i detect collision between the ball and the paddle. To get a better understanding check this out: http://gyazo.com/7bac8acdf0faf66005015d496498ca33
The ball will be inside the circle and reflect off when collides with the paddle.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927189/detecting-collision-of-two-sprites-that-can-rotate/20928531#20928531) which uses an `Area` to detect what "part" of the two shapes are colliding.

Answer (score 0):

a) Try using [Arc2D.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.html#intersects(double,%20double,%20double,%20double)) and convert the circle to a Rectangle (I would avoid it if possible)

b) Use the Method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6312520/4857975).